# c++ find by value in map

Tags: c++, data-structures

I wanted to find in map  by value corresponding key.
I can iterate linearly and find the key, but do we have another better solution if my all values are also unique.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What `map`? `std::map`? Show us you minimal, reproducible example

Comment: map<string, string>

Comment: Use Boost BiMap

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @KP `map<string, string>` doesn't clarify anything at all. We now can at best *assume* that you meant `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, but that's nothing anybody can be sure about, you might be using maps and strings from different namespaces (your own ones from global namespace???)... And if you get more precise, you should [edit] your question appropriately instead of posting comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::find_if`

```
#include <algorithm>

template<typename M, typename V>
auto get_map_iterator_from_value(const M& m, const V& v) {
    return std::find_if(std::begin(m), std::end(m),
                        [&v](const auto& pair) { return pair.second == v; });
}

...

auto it = get_map_iterator_from_value(your_map, your_value);
```

but it'll be slower than when querying on *key* since it too will have to go through every entry in the map until it finds a match.

An improvement, compared to sequenced searching, when searching a map with many entries could be to make use of `std::find_if`s parallel execution support:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

template<typename M, typename V>
auto get_map_iterator_from_value(const M& m, const V& v) {
    return std::find_if(std::execution::par, std::begin(m), std::end(m),
                        [&v](const auto& pair) { return pair.second == v; });
}
```

If that really makes it faster or not has to be tested with your actual map.

Note: If you need to do this often a bidirectional map like [Boost.Bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) is better.

Comment: *'I can iterate linearly'* – well, `std::find_if` doesn't do anything else either, does it?

Comment: @Aconcagua No, it'll have to go through every entry in the map until it finds a match too. It's just an alternative that is easier to improve upon. I've added one possible improvement now.

Comment: @Aconcagua Should I remove the first part of the answer and only keep the part where the search is parallelized?

Comment: I'm fine with mentioning standard `find_if`, I'd just express more clearly that this is nothing else than just another way of iterating linearly over the map (the iteration is simply hidden away inside the function...), because question author explicitly asked for something 'better' (however we might define that...).

Comment: @Aconcagua That's what the "_but it'll be slower than when querying on_ key _since it'll have to go through every entry in the map until it finds a match_" note under the first version is meant to express.  I added a "_too_" to make it clearer.