# Find a value of an element in vector in a std::map < int , std::vector <int >>

Tags: c++

Is there a prettier way to get a value from inside a vector in a map `without using loops`?
For example , How to get the key of the vector which has an element of value `50`?

```
std::map < int , std::vector < int >> myMap;
std::vector < int > a= {10,20,30};
std::vector < int > b= {50,60,70};
myMap.insert({1000,a});
myMap.insert({2000,b});
```

Can I get the key(s) if the value is in more than one vector ?
For Example if `50` Is in both vectors ?

```
std::vector < int > a= {10,20,50};
std::vector < int > b= {50,60,70};
```

Comment: use std::find? Internally, it will result in some kind of loop for the vector and binary search if searching for the key of a map

Comment: Is there a way to write something like , myMap.find the key of the vector which contains a certain value ?

Comment: Maps find things based on the key, not the value. If you want to look at the values, then the map doesn't help with that.

Comment: You can have the vector also as a key of a map, but this helps only if you are comparing against the complete vector and not a single element of a vector. As this it keeps using any kind of loop iterating over the vectors content which is already implemented by std::find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ find by value in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036603/c-find-by-value-in-map)

Comment: What do you mean by "prettier"? You cannot avoid a loop here. You can hide it behind some helper function if you want. Is that what you mean by "prettier"?

Comment: I mean more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a prettier way to get a value from inside a vector in a map without using loops?

You cannot avoid looping the map. But you can avoid writing the loop by using standard algorithm: `std::find_if`.

> I mean more efficient

If you want the lookup to be efficient, then your choice of data structure is not good. You could instead use following:

```
std::unordered_multimap<int, int> myMap{
    {10, 1000},
    {20, 1000},
    {30, 1000},
    {50, 2000},
    {60, 2000},
    {70, 2000},
};
```

With this, the lookup has asymptotically constant complexity instead of linear.

Comment: but here , I will add the complexity of the loop which will unwrap the argument vector elements ?

Comment: @HazemAbaza Copying the vector into your map also has linear complexity.

Comment: This is perfect , As it will also solve the problem of repeated values across vectors
Thanks@eerorika

Answer (score 2):

Here works for every map, value and inner container:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <optional>


template <typename ValueT, typename MapT>
std::optional<typename MapT::key_type> find_key_for_value_contained_in_intern_container(const ValueT& value, const MapT& map) {
    auto key_it = std::find_if(std::begin(map), std::end(map), [&value] (const auto & element) {
        return std::find(std::begin(element.second), std::end(element.second), value) != std::end(element.second);
    });
    return (key_it != std::end(map)) ? key_it->first : std::optional<typename MapT::key_type>();
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::vector<int >> myMap;
    std::vector<int> a = {10, 20, 30};
    std::vector<int> b = {50, 60, 70};
    myMap.insert({1000, a});
    myMap.insert({2000, b});

    int value_to_search{50};

    auto key = find_key_for_value_contained_in_intern_container(value_to_search, myMap);

    if (key)
    std::cout << "Value " << value_to_search << " is at key " << *key << "\n";
}
```

Comment: so what will be the case If the value is in two vectors ?

Comment: It takes the first it can find. BTW please refrain from completly changing the question, because your problems changes. Its likely it will make it less helpful for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be efficient to find the key from the value, and conversely, you could use two maps. If needed, you can encapsulate that into a single class. You are then paying for efficiency of search with space.
Something along the lines of:

```
class DoubleMap {
public:
   DoubleMap() {}

   void insert(int key, std::vector<int> value) {
        myMap1.insert({key, value});
        myMap2.insert({value, key});
   }

   std::vector<int> getValue (int key) {return myMap1[key];}
   int getKey(std::vector<int> value) {return myMap2[value];}

private : 
std::map <int, std::vector<int>> myMap1;
std::map<std::vector<int>, int> myMap2;
}
```

I wouldn't advise this kind of heavy class unless you really need the efficiency of search in both directions, though.